# Using pure JavaScript trying to change the default option of select box, but having an uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, select

Using vanilla JavaScript I am trying to change the default option of a select box.

```
var temp = "Approve";
var mySelect = document.querySelector('[id^="select_leave_action_"]').id;

for(var i, j = 0; i = mySelect.options[j]; j++) {
    if(i.value == temp) {
        mySelect.selectedIndex = j;
        break;
    }
}
```

When I execute the above code I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at :4:39`

What is wrong with my code?

I tried to use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `querySelector`, but still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `.id`.

The ID is a string and won't have an `options` property. You want to store the select element itself (not its ID) to access its options.

(Also it's even simpler to just set `mySelect.value = temp`, the only difference to your current method will be how the case is handled where `temp` is not existing in the options that exist. Depending on the browser, setting the value directly may display the box empty if no fitting option exists.)

Comment: Additionally, you could just do `mySelect.value = temp;` instead of that loop.

Comment: Yes. There is a small difference though. I added it to the answer.